# how to turn multiple observables into a completable?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm new to RxSwift and just inherited an old codebase, so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

In the code, data gets updated with the help of Completables and Observables. Below are two methods that loosely illustrate how that's done (obfuscated a bit for privacy purposes):

```
// note: `getNewData()` returns an Observable
func refreshData() -> Completable {
    dataManager.getNewData()
        .map { DataRepresentation(fromObject: $0) }
        .take(1)
        .asSingle()
        .flatMapCompletable { data in
            self.storageManager.save(data: data)
        }
}

// STORAGE MANAGER

func save(data: DataRepresentation) -> Completable {
    do {
        // PSEUDOCODE: save the data, emit an event about it if necessary.
        return Completable.completed()
    } catch let error {
        return Completable.error(error)
    }
}
```

So, my question is this: let's assume `getNewData()` allows me to pass in some parameters which will make it so that I don't just get the same data back every time. Moreover, let's say I want to call that method n times, wait for all the calls to come back, then still return a Completable from `refreshData()` (as to not need to change its signature). Is that sort of thing possible? I was looking into `.zip` but I'm not sure if it applies here. Thanks.

Comment: Where are these parameters for the updated `getNewData()` coming from?

Comment: To keep things simple, let's say they'd come from within the `refreshData()` method itself. In this app, data gets fetched in date ranges, and in this case, I'll need to grab one month's worth of data per API call (though multiple month-sized chunks per `refreshData()` call). So, we could, for example, say: get me the data for April, May, and June -- if that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "they'd come from within the method"... Then you say they come from an api call? Does this API call return an Observable array of items that `getNewData()` will accept as parameters?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I'm definitely making things confusing with the hypotheticals. I was using "API call" to refer to a call to `getNewData()`. A (hopefully) more clear example of what I was aiming for would be this: let's say we added a new first line to `refreshData()`, and it read `let myInputs = [1,2,3]`. Then  `getNewData()` became `getNewData(input: Int)`. From there, I'd fire off n (in this case, 3) calls to `getNewData(input: Int)` (one per entry in `myInputs`), merge all 3 return values into an array / observable array, and save that via `storageManager.save()`.  Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated solution based on all the comments:

```
final class Example {
    let dataManager: DataManager
    let storageManager: StorageManager

    init(dataManager: DataManager, storageManager: StorageManager) {
        self.dataManager = dataManager
        self.storageManager = storageManager
    }

    func refreshData() -> Completable {
        let myInputs = [1,2,3]
        return Observable.zip(myInputs.map(dataManager.getNewData))
            .map { $0.map(DataRepresentation.init(fromObject:)) }
            .asSingle()
            .flatMapCompletable { [storageManager] representations in
                storageManager.save(representations)
            }
    }
}

struct DataManager {
    let getNewData: (Int) -> Observable<Data>
}

struct StorageManager {
    let save: ([DataRepresentation]) -> Completable
}

struct DataRepresentation: Equatable {
    let fromObject: Data
}
```

Here is a test harness showing that it works (with extensive comments):

```
final class ExampleTests: XCTestCase {
    let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
    // monitors the values sent to DataManager's `getNewData`
    lazy var dataManagerArgs = scheduler.createObserver(Int.self)
    // monitors the values sent to StorageManger's `save`.
    lazy var storageManagerArgs = scheduler.createObserver([DataRepresentation].self)
    // expect to receive an array of three `DataRepresentation` objects one second after the completable is
    //   subscribed to
    let expectedStorageManagerArgs = parseTimeline(
        "-*",
        values: [
            "*": [
                DataRepresentation(fromObject: "A".data(using: .utf8)!),
                DataRepresentation(fromObject: "B".data(using: .utf8)!),
                DataRepresentation(fromObject: "C".data(using: .utf8)!)
            ]
        ])
        .offsetTime(by: 200)

    func test_happy_path() {
        // this DataManager sends either "A", "B", or "C" and then a completed event for each subscription.
        let dataManager = createDataManager(timeline: { "-\($0)|" })

        // this StorageManager sends a completed event after it's subscribed to.
        let storageManager = createStorageManager(timeline: { _ in "-|" })

        let sut = Example(dataManager: dataManager, storageManager: storageManager)
        let result = scheduler.start {
            sut.refreshData() // call `refreshData()` and record the result of the Completable event.
        }

        // expect to receive all three values as `refreshData` is called.
        let expectedDataManagerArgs = parseTimelineEvents("*", values: { _ in [1, 2, 3] }).offsetTime(by: 100)
        XCTAssertEqual(dataManagerArgs.events, expectedDataManagerArgs[0])

        XCTAssertEqual(storageManagerArgs.events, expectedStorageManagerArgs[0])

        // expect for the `refreshData` completable to complete after the `save` completes.
        let expectedResult = parseTimeline("--|", values: { _ in fatalError() }).offsetTime(by: 200)
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, expectedResult[0])
    }

    func test_getNewData_failure() {
        // this DataManager sends either "A", or "C", and then a completed event for subscriptions 1 and 3.
        //   it sends an error for subscription 2
        let dataManager = createDataManager(timeline: { $0 == 2 ? "-#" : "-\($0)|" })

        // this StorageManager sends a completed event after it's subscribed to.
        let storageManager = createStorageManager(timeline: { _ in "-|" })

        let sut = Example(dataManager: dataManager, storageManager: storageManager)
        let result = scheduler.start {
            sut.refreshData() // call `refreshData()` and record the result of the Completable event.
        }

        // expect to receive all three values as `refreshData` is called.
        let expectedDataManagerArgs = parseTimelineEvents("*", values: { _ in [1, 2, 3] }).offsetTime(by: 100)
        XCTAssertEqual(dataManagerArgs.events, expectedDataManagerArgs[0])

        // a single error from `getNewData` means no save events.
        XCTAssertEqual(storageManagerArgs.events, [])

        // expect for the `refreshData` completable to emit an error when the getNewData fails.
        let expectedResult = parseTimeline("-#", values: { _ in fatalError() }).offsetTime(by: 200)
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, expectedResult[0])
    }

    func test_save_error() {
        // this DataManager sends either "A", "B", or "C" and then a completed event for each subscription.
        let dataManager = createDataManager(timeline: { "-\($0)|" })

        // this StorageManager sends an error one second after it's subscribed to.
        let storageManager = createStorageManager(timeline: { _ in "-#" })

        let sut = Example(dataManager: dataManager, storageManager: storageManager)
        let result = scheduler.start {
            sut.refreshData() // call `refreshData()` and record the result of the Completable event.
        }

        // expect to receive all three values as `refreshData` is called.
        let expectedDataManagerArgs = parseTimelineEvents("*", values: { _ in [1, 2, 3] }).offsetTime(by: 100)
        XCTAssertEqual(dataManagerArgs.events, expectedDataManagerArgs[0])

        XCTAssertEqual(storageManagerArgs.events, expectedStorageManagerArgs[0])

        // expect for the `refreshData` completable to emit an error when the save fails.
        let expectedResult = parseTimeline("--#", values: { _ in fatalError() }).offsetTime(by: 200)
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, expectedResult[0])
    }

    func createDataManager(timeline: @escaping (Int) -> String) -> DataManager {
        DataManager(getNewData: scheduler.mock(
            args: dataManagerArgs,
            values: ["1": "A".data(using: .utf8)!, "2": "B".data(using: .utf8)!, "3": "C".data(using: .utf8)!],
            timelineSelector: timeline
        ))
    }

    func createStorageManager(timeline: @escaping ([DataRepresentation]) -> String) -> StorageManager {
        StorageManager(save: { [scheduler, storageManagerArgs] value in
            scheduler.mock(args: storageManagerArgs, values: ["N": ()], timelineSelector: timeline)(value)
                .ignoreElements()
                .asCompletable()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! Still trying to fully comprehend everything here. In the first solution you gave, do I not already have the array I want in the `flatMapCompletable ` block? If I make my storage / save call (instead of `Completable.zip...`) there, the compiler is satisfied. However, if I replace that save call with `Completable.zip...`, the compiler complains that it can't convert value of type `([DataRepresentation]) -> Completable` to the expected type, `(DataRepresentation) throws -> Completable`. Again, thanks very much for your help! I know we're in the weeds here!

Comment: The data in the flatMapCompletable block comes from the `getNewData()` function. You said in your question that you were changing that function to accept a parameter... Is that not the case? Maybe clarify the question a bit...

Comment: Yes, you were definitely correct to add a parameter to `getNewData()`. That's my end goal. I added some more details in my latest comment on the original question ... should help clarify a bit more (I hope). Just let me know if not.

Comment: Well then the first option in this answer is correct. Just rename `parameters` to `myInputs` and move it into the function.

Comment: The implication of your first comment above is that you have not given me the correct type for `save(data:)`. Did you change it to something like `save(data: [DataRepresentation])`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right -- I'd be looking to have the signature be `save(data: [DataRepresentation])`. I should have just written the question as such from the get go; my apologies. Is that option possible?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! The compiler is happy now, but I'm still having trouble getting the `flatMapCompletable` block to get called. Any idea why that might be the case? Really appreciate all your help here.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the returned Completable? I just ran the code through a test harness and everything worked...

Comment: Yup, I was indeed subscribing; good question. I found what I think is the source of the issue: similar "API" methods (similar to `getNewData()`, that is) in the program call `.take(1)`, which I assume means "wait for one response / emission rather than n." I added that same line to `getNewData()`, and now the `flatMapCompletable` block gets called. I'm going to proceed with that unless it seems wildly off-base. Thanks so much -- I'll mark your solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: @BrianSachetta Here you go, I added the test harness I used to prove it works... It uses my [MarbleTest.swift](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools/blob/main/Tests/Test-Tools/TestScheduler%2BMarbleTests.swift) code.

Comment: Wow that's unreal. Thanks again!